# Put C++ function arguments on individual lines

Tags: formatting

I often find myself having to reformat C++ function arguments and template parameters to occupy individual lines rather than being on the same line. Here are a few examples.

Turn this

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<some_type_trait<T>, int> foo(const T&);
```

into this

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<
    some_type_trait<T>,
    int
> foo(const T&);
```

Turn this

```cpp
double inner_product(const std::array<double,3>& a, const std::array<double,3>& b);
```

into this

```cpp
double inner_product(
    const std::array<double,3>& a,
    const std::array<double,3>& b
);
```

Does a plugin that does that already exist? If not, can someone help me write a vim function for it?
What I'd like to do is put the cursor inside the outer parentheses or angle brackets and press a key combination to reformat the arguments to individual lines. Not recursively. Just the top level. The number of arguments can be arbitrary. And, as I tried to illustrate in the second example, there may be additional commas that don't separate arguments.
So, a bit similarly to how `vim-surround` works, except, instead of replacing the type of brackets, I want the code inside the brackets reformatted.

Comment: Using clang-format as an external formatting tools seems to become increasingly popular. Has the advantage that everybody working on a project will have the same formatting, regardless of their editor. Instead of wasting time tweaking your editor, you'll waste time tweaking clang-format.

Comment: A comment on vim SO that advocates not doing something in vim. lol

Comment: Glad my comment amused you. I wasn't so much advocating as mentioning what is - in my experience - a common setup. I don't even like it, if you must know.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

With tpope/vim-surround, I believe `cSbb` and `cS>>` would do, since the `S` forces multi-line. You might have to touch up the insides (like `:substitute/,/&\r/g`) afterwards; I’m not able to test and confirm at the moment.

Comment: From what I can tell, the difference is that `cSbb` in `vim-surrond` autoindents the affected lines afterwards. I like what `vim-argwrap` does better. But thanks for chipping in. I didn't know `vim-surrond` basically solved the problem already.

Answer (score 1):

I found an existing plugin that does exactly what I wanted.

[vim-argwrap](https://github.com/FooSoft/vim-argwrap/)